# How "far" different is the Lie 3-group away from the manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

We know every Lie group is a differentiable manifold, whose local space behaves like $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is:

1. [Can the Lie 3-group be manifold?](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+3-group)
2. If not, how "far" different is the Lie 3-group away from the manifold?

Comment: This is incomprehensible.

Comment: You should provide a detailed definition of a Lie 3-group if you expect to get an answer.